# Is variable assignment within if conditions possible?

Tags: tcl

You know how in C and JavaScript variable assignments can take place within conditions, such as

```
if ( boolean || (val = func(args)) == case1 ) {
  /* Perform A */
} else if ( val == case2) {
  /* Perform B */
} ...
```

such that don't need to write another `elseif` to perform code A.

Can this be done in Tcl; and, if so, how?

It's not very important but I'd like to know just the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set` and other commands in an `expr`-ression, and `set` returns the newly assigned value, so...

```
set boolean true
proc func {} { return case2 }

if {$boolean && [set val [func]] eq "case1"} {
    puts "case 1 found"
} elseif {$val eq "case2"} {
    puts "case 2 found"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm embarrassed by my stupidity. I don't know why but I was thinking `[set ...]` returned `0` or `1`. which makes no sense at all, I know. Trying to learn too much too quickly for my little brain.

Comment: (Though in this particular contrived example, if boolean is false var won't get set so if it doesn't already exist the elseif line will raise an error)